# Setup a mocked injected object

Tags: ninject, nsubstitute

I've configured a `MockingKernel` in order to mock a dependency:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestsFixture
{
    private NSubstituteMockingKernel IoCKernel;

    public UsersTests()
    {
        this.IoCKernel = new NSubstituteMockingKernel();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.IoCKernel.Reset();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AddUserTest()
    {
        var mock = this.IoCKernel.Bind<Core.Configuration.ICoreConfiguration>().ToMock();
        mock.Setup( <<<<<<< How to substitute methods of this mocked objects??????
            m =>
            m.UserIdentities
                .Returns(new List<UserIdentity>() {new UserIdentity("user1")}
        );

        Core.Kernel coreKernel = this.IoCKernel.Get<Core.Kernel>();
    }
}
```

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.MockingKernel/wiki/Examples) I need to call a `Setup` method in order to substitute methods. Nevertheless, `Setup` method is not available.

Any ideas?

I've read documentation. I'm asking for some examples. Nevertheless, I think that documentation is a bit poor.

**EDIT**

I've tried this:

```
public void Test() {

    Core.Configuration.UserIdentity userConfiguration = Core.Configuration.UserIdentity.Create("u1", "p1");
    IEnumerable<Core.Configuration.UserIdentity> configurationUsers = new List<Core.Configuration.UserIdentity>() { userConfiguration };

    this.IoCKernel.Get<Core.Configuration.ICoreConfiguration>().UserIdentities.Returns(configurationUsers);

    //Testing
    Core.Kernel kernel = this.IoCKernel.Get<Core.Kernel>();
    kernel.Received(1).AddUser(Arg.Any<Core.Identity.UserIdentity>());
}
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting this `NSubstitute.Exceptions.NotASubstituteException` exception message now on last line:

> NSubstitute extension methods like .Received() can only be called on objects created using Substitute.For() and related methods.

As you can see I'm trying to test `AddUser` method is called once at least. `AddUser` must be called according my `Core.Kernel` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.MockingKernel.NSubstitute;
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            using (var kernel = new NSubstituteMockingKernel())
            {
                var substitute = kernel.Get<IDummyService>();
                substitute.ReturnInt().Returns(1);

                var instance = kernel.Get<DummyClass>();
                Assert.AreEqual(1, instance.Calc());
                substitute.Received(1).ReturnInt();
            }
        }

        public interface IDummyService
        {
            int ReturnInt();
        }

        public class DummyClass
        {
            private IDummyService _dummyService;

            public DummyClass(IDummyService dummyService)
            {
                _dummyService = dummyService;
            }

            public int Calc()
            {
                return _dummyService.ReturnInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following packages:

```
PM> Get-Package

Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName                                                                                                                                                                           
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                                                                           
Ninject                             {3.2.2.0}                                ClassLibrary1                                                                                                                                                                         
Ninject.MockingKernel               {3.2.2.0}                                ClassLibrary1                                                                                                                                                                         
Ninject.MockingKernel.NSubstitute   {3.2.2.0}                                ClassLibrary1                                                                                                                                                                         
NSubstitute                         {1.10.0.0}                               ClassLibrary1                                                                                                                                                                         
NUnit                               {3.6.0}                                  ClassLibrary1
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandr. I've tried the code added on post now. Nevertheless, I'm getting an exception message...

Comment: @Jordi What exception do you get? Could you share more details please.

Comment: The exception type is `NSubstitute.Exceptions.NotASubstituteException`...

Comment: I'm really confused. I need some help. I've created a [repository on github](https://github.com/jeusdi/MockingKernel). Could you take a look on `Solution -> Tests -> Kernle.Tests -> Users -> UserTests.cs`. Currently, I don't know what am I doing. It crashes but I don't have strengh enought to solve it. I think by this way, you could help me better I's nog going to be necessary to abstract the situation. Could you  help me?

Comment: I've create a [gitter room](https://gitter.im/MockingKernel/Lobby?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link) in order to be able to talk a bit better.